# open json files in a loop - formatting problem

Tags: python, loops, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I need to open files in my s3 bucket and those are the files:

[image]

I want to apply some piece of code on each of them, hence I want to open them in a loop.

But I have a problem with formatting. The files are between 1 and 999, I cannot loop though range 1, 999 :

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    file_to_predict = spark.read.json(f"s3a://mu_bucket/company_v20_dl/part-00{i}.gz")
```

i will be replaced with 1, 2 etc, I would like it to be replaced with 001, 002 etc <- taking three spaces (as the highest is 999 - taking 3 spaces). Do you perhaps know how to deal with such case?

[EDIT]
I am able to open single file without unzipping it:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think a GZ file would have JSON content?

Comment: I checked the data and I run already single file - I am able to open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files have GZ extension. That's a common extension for GZip. Whatever is in those zipped files, you need to unzip them first.

Other than that, use `{i:03d}` for a 3 digit number with leading zeros.